# I can click on a link outside of its text element?

Tags: html, css

I have a h3 link somewhere at the bottom of a page and not only does the link expand to the whole row, but also in a row higher than the h3 element. I'll explain better using this screenshot:

Where the arrows are pointing at is where I can actually click the link outside of  the h3 element (Become part of the innovation is the actual link). 
Any ideas on how to make the link be clickable only on the text and what is causing this?

Comment: Post your code to your question please.

Comment: Sorry, I've added the code.

Comment: @CRover Pastebin links will mean nothing if Pastebin goes down. Could you please include the relevant code within the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Put the link inside the header

Because you're relatively positioning the `h3`, it is moving down page relative to where it would be otherwise, but the `a` tag isn't being positioned and therefore remains where it was in addition to containing the new position of the `h3`.

Consider the following simple example where the `h3` is relatively positioned to the right by 50%. If you hover to the left of `a>h3`, you'll see that it is clickable, but if you hover to the left of `h3>a`, you'll see that it is not clickable.

```css
h3 {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><h3>a&gt;h3</h3></a>
<h3><a href="#">h3&gt;a</a></h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

It may help if you could provide a bit of code like the footer as it seems your problem lay there.

From what I see what you want to do would be something like this.

```
<div>
<h3><a href="#">Become part of the innovation</a></h3>
</div>
<footer>
<img1 src="#"/>
<img2 src="#"/>
<img3 src="#"/>
<img4 src="#"/>
<img5 src="#"/>
</footer>
```

I may be wrong so if I am please add your code so we can look into

Answer (score 0):

I've added a code snippet to your question based upon your pastebin's. Potentially it's because your image for css.png isn't complete:

```
<img src="imgs/css.png"
```

Also, you img are self closing tags so you should simply do:

```
<img src="imgs/css.png" alt="CSS" />
```

Also, make sure you have an `alt` tag, even if it's empty.

Also gfullam posted before I could finish an edit, his answer is quite correct :).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my mistake,

```
<a href="#"><h3>Become part of the innovation</h3></a>
```

should be

```
<h3><a href="#">Become part of the innovation</a></h3>
```

You can see the result here https://jsfiddle.net/L5fbqrc5/